# Enabling TLS 1.2 on a windows executable which is in .Netframework 2.0

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

I have a windows executable application on my desktop (Windows 10 desktop) which was build in .Net framework 2.0 (v2.0.50727) for which I need to enable TLS 1.2 communication with a server (the server currently supports only TLS 1.2 traffic) and is blocking the application now:

Below are few details regarding the application:

1. The exe file calls dbmlsync.exe on SAP SQL Anywhere 12 which is installed on my desktop (I have read in internet SQL Anywhere 12 supports TLS 1.2 by default) so should not be a problem.
2. I may not be able to make changes to the code of the executable (since this is a very old code) and I was checking ways on to force the application to use the TLS enabled on the OS.

Below are the changes that I have made:

1. I have made changes in the configuration file of the executable to use .NetFramework 4.0 while runtime and to use the TLS enabled on the OS by default. (.Netframework 4.0 is available in my desktop).
2. Made changes in the registry of my desktop
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727
   Create a new entry SystemDefaultTlsVersions with a DWORD value set to 1.

Create a registry entry DefaultSecureProtocols on the following location:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp
Set the DWORD value to 800 for TLS 1.2.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols
Created a folder as TLS 1.2 and two subkeys under it Client and server and both are having DisabledByDefault as 0 and Enabled as 1.

After making all these changes I rebooted my machine and verified using Netmon still the application is sending protocol as TLS 1.1. Can anyone please help? I have read in many question .Net 2.0 application can be enabled to use TLS 1.2 without making change in code. I tried various suggestions but nothing is helping me much

Comment: This is the changes that I included in the application config file as part of point 1 
  <configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>

<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions=false"/>

</runtime>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you saw that SQL Anywhere 12 supports TLS 1.2 by default but it's wrong.

"The SQL Anywhere web server supports HTTPS connections using SSL version 3.0 and TLS version 1.0." on [SQL Anywhere 12 documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbadmin/ml-tls-s-3599504.html).

So to work your server must support TLS 1.0 unfortunately.

1. [SQL Anywhere 12 -> TLS 1.0](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbadmin/ml-tls-s-3599504.html)
2. [SQL Anywhere 16 -> TLS 1.1](http://dcx.sybase.com/sa160/en/dbadmin/ml-tls-s-3599504.html)
3. [SQL Anywhere 17 -> TLS 1.2](https://help.sap.com/doc/b3ff66e1dd76433ea68d1848af6d761d/17.0/en-US/Behaviour-changes-and-whats-New-en.pdf)